# Animating a UICollectionViewCell: Scroll To And Resize At The Same Time

Tags: animation, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to get a UICollectionViewCell to do an animated resize and at the same time have the collection view scroll the cell to the top of the collection view's viewport.

When I do

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
}
```

with

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.isSelected) {
        return self.collectionView.frame.size;
    }
    else {
        return CGSizeMake(300, 100);
    }
}
```

the scroll happens before the resize animation.

And if I call scrollToItemAtIndexPath inside of performBatchUpdates like

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

it doesn't work most of the time.

Thanks!

-Eric

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to achieve an effect like this is to simply subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and tweak cell layout attributes based on the selected cell.